# AttributeError when using validatecommand on a Spinbox

Tags: python, class, attributes, tkinter

I am doing a test writing a script that validate a spinbox to implement it on a larger system, but I am struggling with python because it is warning that there is no spinbox attribute on my `Window` class. Check my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window:

  def __init__(self, toplevel):

    self.spinbox = Spinbox(toplevel, from_ = 0, to = 10,
                           validate = 'all', validatecommand = self.validate)
    self.spinbox.pack()

  def validate(self):

    print self.spinbox.get()

root = Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the error it is giving:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\DOCS\FILIPE\PROGRAMMING\PYTHON\Tkinter sandbox\01 - spinbox validate.
py", line 13, in validate
    print self.spinbox.get()
AttributeError: Window instance has no attribute 'spinbox'
```

Anyone could help me with this one?

Comment: Don't add an answer to the question, either post your own answer, or accept someone else's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I MANAGED TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM USING TEXTVARIABLES AND THE TRACE METHOD

```
    #Validates
    self.countstringvar = StringVar()
    self.countstringvar.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode,
        sv = self.countstringvar: self.noLettersValidate(sv, self.count))

    self.starsstringvar = StringVar()
    self.starsstringvar.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode,
        sv = self.starsstringvar: self.noLettersValidate(sv, self.stars))

    self.scorestringvar = StringVar()
    self.scorestringvar.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode,
        sv = self.scorestringvar: self.noLettersValidate(sv, self.score))

    self.count['textvariable'] = self.countstringvar
    self.stars['textvariable'] = self.starsstringvar
    self.score['textvariable'] = self.scorestringvar

  def removeLetters(self, s):

    a = []
    for i in s:
      if i.isdigit():
        a.append(i)
    return ''.join(a)

  def noLettersValidate(self, sv, w):

    w.text(self.removeLetters(sv.get()))
```

### Thanks for everyone contributions!

Answer (score 0):

If you add some `print` statements to your code:

```
class Window:
  def __init__(self, toplevel):
    print "A start", self, self.__dict__
    self.spinbox = Spinbox(toplevel, from_ = 0, to = 10,
                           validate = 'all', validatecommand = self.validate)
    self.spinbox.pack()
    print "A end", self, self.__dict__

  def validate(self):
    print "B", self, self.__dict__
    print self.spinbox.get()
#...
```

You get the output:

```
A start <__main__.Window instance at 0x7fe4f8deec20> {}
B <__main__.Window instance at 0x7fe4f8deec20> {}
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "t.py", line 14, in validate
    print self.spinbox.get()
AttributeError: Window instance has no attribute 'spinbox'
A end <__main__.Window instance at 0x7fe4f8deec20> {'spinbox': <Tkinter.Spinbox instance at 0x7fe4f8e0da28>}
```

This means that the validate function is called inside the constructor to validate the initial value, and at that point `self.spinbox` has not yet been set. You will need to either check if you are still constructing or delay setting `validatecommand` like this:

```
self.spinbox = Spinbox(toplevel, from_ = 0, to = 10,
                       validate = 'all')
self.spinbox["validatecommand"] = self.validate
self.spinbox.pack()
```

Comment: thanks now it works, but it only call the validate function once... :(

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira: your function needs to return `True` or `False`, and it can't modify the spinbox. Otherwise Tkinter will turn off validation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Bryan, but how can I prevent the user from entering text to my Spinbox?

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira: if the validation returns false, the key that the user pressed will be ignored.

Comment: @BryanOakley I made a test with a validate function returning false and the key wasn't ignored.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira: I would have to see your code. This is exactly what `validatecommand` is designed for - if the function returns false the edit made by the user is rejected. That's its only purpose, and it _does_ work. To say it doesn't work means you're doing something wrong, but without seeing what you're doing it's impossible to say.